# FileNotFoundError: and driver_scaling_report.html

Tags: openmdao

I am having trouble debugging my openmdao model with the ScipyOptimizeDriver.

The model inputs are a vector of design variables and the scalar output is calculated in a separate flow solver. This does involve a setting up directories to save the results from the flow solver but this is separate from where the openmdao python file is located, which I think could be part of the problem. The error is shown below:

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'reports/problem1/driver_scaling_report.html'

The file is evidently missing from the current directory but I am not sure why, when I run the actuator disk example problem this file is automatically generated in the correct place.

Comment: Without seeing your code it's difficult to determine what could be going on here.  It seems possible the code is in some other directory at the time it is trying to build the reports.  As a workaround, you can disable automatic report generation with by setting the environment variable `OPENMDAO_REPORTS = 0`

Comment: Disabling the automatic report generation worked. Many Thanks